# not handling the file upload window well

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a page object called **import_transaction_file.rb**, which one of the method **click_choose_file** will invoke a standard file upload windows show below:

the code for the page object is:

```
class ImportTransactionFile
  include PageObject
  ....
  button(:choose_file, :id => 'createBulkPayment:file')
  ....
  def click_choose_file
    choose_file
  end

end
```

In my test program below:

```
....
def test_go_to_direct_credit_payment_page
    ...
    @import_transaction.click_choose_file

 #   @browser.window(:title => 'File Upload').use do
 #     @browser.button(:name => 'Cancel').click
 #   end
 # doesn't work
  end
```

the method click_choose_file in the test program will invoke the standard file upload window as attached below:
[image]

How do I:

- put the path to file name
- click open button
- click close button

Will you recommend me to do it in the page-object or the test program?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: There is a class for dealing with file upload inputs - ie `<input type="file">`. However, I do not think it gives methods for the actual dialog. Is your button activating a file upload input that is not visible?

Comment: The button activates a upload window is visible on the html. I located this button by its ID. So you are saying in Watir there is no methods to select a file in the file upload window and click "Open"?

Comment: I was given the impression in the past that the file upload window is really an OS thing rather than a browser thing. I am guessing that is why Watir does not have a full library around interacting with the file upload popup. Instead, there is just enough implemented to interact with the popup in the typical use case - ie interacting with a `<input type="file">` element. This is why I was hoping that your page was using a file field under the covers - ie then you could use the built in methods. I would suggest you create (or find) a page that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar thing to what you're asking and mine works using:

```
browser.file_field(:text, "File Upload").set("C:\path\to\file\to\upload")
```

Hope that helps!